# Getting java.net.MalformedURLException in MonoDeveloper

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, libgdx, ikvm

Hey I am new to MonoDeveloper.  I am trying to port libgdx code to iOS platform.  My Libgdx code runs perfectly on desktop & Android phone.
           But when i run it on iPhone simulator with MonoDeveloper its giving me this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: 0   iosgame   
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: file.
0x000e8932 mono_handle_exception_internal_first_pass + 3058 1 iosgame                             
0x000ea012 mono_handle_exception_internal + 1602 2   iosgame                     
0x000eab5f mono_handle_exception + 47 3   iosgame                     
0x0012dcb2 mono_x86_throw_exception + 306 4   ???                     
0x0b73df8f 0x0 + 192143247 at java.net.URL..ctor (java.net.URL,string)
<IL 0x00004, 0x00018> at java.net.URL..ctor (string) 
<IL 0x00003, 0x00018> at java.net.URI.toURL () 
<IL 0x00023, 0x00064> at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.MakeResourceURL(System.Reflection.Assembly,string) 
<IL 0x00016, 0x0006c> at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader/AssemblyLoader.FindResources(string) 
<IL 0x0003c, 0x00084> at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader/<GetResourcesImpl>c__Iterator0.MoveNext() 
<IL 0x00068, 0x00070> at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader/<GetResourcesImpl>c__Iterator0.MoveNext() 
<IL 0x003dc, 0x0069f> at IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.getResource(java.lang.ClassLoader,System.Reflection.Assembly,string) 
<IL 0x00034, 0x0009c> at ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.getResource(java.lang.ClassLoader,System.Reflection.Assembly,string) 
<IL 0x00006, 0x00018> at ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.getResource (string) 
<IL 0x00000, 0x0001c>
```

Kindly give me suggestion where i am wrong.

Comment: Does the backtrace go farther?  All the code in the backtrace is internal to IKVM, so its not clear what's happening in your code (if its even gotten to your code yet).  I'd guess you're trying to load some assets at this point, but its not clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug in libgdx or in IKVM, the library used to port Java code to the the .NET/Mono runtime. Have you reported it to the libgdx developers?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the MonoTouch port of IKVM doesn't include the "file" protocol handler.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the issue myself.

In the stack trace, it'll mention which line of your Java code is calling the MalformedURLException. So for example: *Example.java:208*

Locate line 208 of *Example.java*, and see what file it's stumbling on.

Next, locate this file inside Xamarin/mono studio and right click on it.
Then go down to "Build Option" > "BundleResource".

Answer (score 0):

Based on a past question (from the same user) I think this is the output of a [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15309671/220643) reaction. Apple recently began to refuse application **executables** bigger than 60MB.

That's huge, a basic hello world application created with Xamarin.iOS is under 3 MB and that's the total **application** size. The executable itself is under 2.2MB and includes the Mono runtime, the *linked* base class libraries (BCL) and the *unlinked* user code.

Now this 2.2MB size is achieved because the BCL is **linked** (by default **Link SDK** is used for device builds). That means everything that is **not** used, in the BCL, is removed. If the BCL was **not** linked (it can be disabled if you're curious) then the executable size would be **46 MB** - more than 20x bigger! (and that's part of the reasons why you should **never** disable the linker on device builds).

LibGDX is a Java library. It can work with Xamarin.iOS by being converted to .NET using IKVM. That converts the GDX library **and** the Java class libraries. All of this is **user code** (i.e. stuff you added) and not **SDK** code (i.e. code shipped by Xamarin). IOW the linker does not, by default, remove anything from GDX (or IKVM libraries).

So, **by default**, everything in GDX **and** Java (class lib) is being AOT'ed into the native executable - leading it over Apple's limit (which was the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15309671/220643)).

The previous answer was to use **Link all assemblies**, IOW run the linker on all the application managed code. That removes a lot of unused code and results in smaller applications and executable size (see the hello world example above).

However it goes back to the main linker limitation. It use static analysis to detect unused code - and reflection (from .NET or Java) is dynamic. So the linker needs help to preserve (using `[Preserve]` attribute or [an XML file](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/linker-versus-customization/)) code used thru reflection.

I have **not** seen the Java code handling protocols - but I'm pretty sure it use reflection to load a type based on the scheme (e.g. `file`) and that type(s) needs to be preserved to work correctly at runtime. Once preserved I'm sure the application will work properly (and without being improperly large).

Answer (score -1):

Is there a point after the "unknown protocol: file"? In this case a classpath URI is wrong. It look like that there is any setting wrongs. A file URL should start with:

```
file:
```

And the error message look like that it start with:

```
file.
```