# iOS App's executable file size exceeded

Tags: ios, executable, arm64

In my project, when `Valid Architectures` is `armv7 armv7s`,the size of my app's executable file is 45MB.

But, when `Valid Architectures` is `armv7 armv7s arm64` , the size of my app's executable file is 90+ MB.

So, when I submit my app , I got an error

> invalid executable size, the size of your app's executable file
>   app_Name is 94208000 bytes,which exceeds the maximum allowed size of
>   80MB.

I think,if add `arm64`, the code is compiled twice - once for 32 and once for 64-bit architectures. But the executable size is too large.

Do you have any idea what I can do about this?

Comment: the top words is "Hi , all",not "all.", sorry.

Comment: Hello JTZS. Neither "Hi, all" nor "all" are necessary. We are all friendly people here at Stackoverflow, so we just assume that everyone says "Hi" and "Thanks" all the times. That's why we don't put it in our questions and answers. That leaves more room for the actual question. Especially since the first couple lines of your question are shown in the [question list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions). And we don't want to waste that valuable space with greetings.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch : No ,and ,it can cause the error ?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch : Thank you about your advice;

Comment: You have 45MB of executable?  How did you manage that? My project with 1.6M lines of code compiles to 10MB unstripped.

Comment: @Variable Length Coder : My project with more than 15M lines of code. And it has 850+ .cpp and .mm files .

Answer (score 1):

Definitely this will happen as you are trying to build for multiple architectures.

I just found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309671/invalid-executable-size-from-itunes-connect) with some good suggestions for how to reduce build size. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Good to be of help. If it solves your problem please accept this answer.

Comment: I tried . But the size of my app's executable file is still 90+ MB. Well, if we add "arm64", the code is compiled twice, and executable file's size  will be larger.  So , The Apple want us add "arm64", why the executable file still exceeds the maximum allowed size of 80MB ?

Comment: Here is a suggestion. You could write a webservice which would download your assets (maybe a few assets) from a webserver on the first launch of the application. Just keeping a loading screen. and later you can use these assets from documents directory.

Comment: That's a good idea, and we did that.  My project has 850+ .cpp and .mm files,so it's causes executable file's size be 40+ MB. and if add "arm64", it will be 90+ MB. So ,  executable file's size be 90+MB is mormal, or my app support 64-bit operation is not finished ?

Comment: I dont think that only .cpp and .mm files would contribute to 40+ MB. What about the images you are using? Also other think that could increase your app size is the third parties that you use. Check if you any extra framework or third parties are added

Comment: I will check that. Thank you  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can drop support for `armv7s`. All those devices can use the `armv7` slice. It is no longer needed, and not included by default in Xcode 6's settings.

Comment: Thank you, But Apple says 'As we announced in October, beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements'. So , my project must support 64-bit.

Comment: Yes. `armv7s` is just another 32 bit architecture. In my projects I am doing `armv7` and `arm64`. So if you remove `armv7s` you will save a lot of space.

Comment: I tried your way , I remove ‘armv7s‘ ,but it's not save a lot of space , this app's executable file is till 90+ MB.