# libgdx on ios GdxRuntimeException couldn't load file

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, libgdx, ikvm, xamarin-studio

I decided to move my application from Android to iOS. Application use libgdx library. I generated ios subproject using libgdx and opened it using Xamarin Studio. All images are linked from my-project-android/assets/data. All images have set build Action > content. Now every time when run project from xamarin studio i get GdxRuntimeException Coldn't load file: data/background.png. This file is the first image which i load in my application.

All operation i have done on my mac both with simulator and iPhone device.

StackTrace:

```
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: /data/background.png ---> System.Exception: unknown protocol: file
at java.net.URL..ctor (java.net.URL context, System.String spec, java.net.URLStreamHandler handler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap..ctor (com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle file) [0x0004c] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.java:140
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare () [0x00052] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FileTextureData.java:64
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load (TextureData data) [0x00036] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java:175
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create (TextureData data) [0x0000d] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java:159
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture..ctor (com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle file, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Format format, Boolean useMipMaps) [0x00060] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java:133
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture..ctor (com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle file) [0x00001] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java:122
at com.kaproel.trafficControlManager.MainMenuScreen..ctor (com.kaproel.trafficControlManager.trafficControl game) [0x00088] in /Users/Piotr/Developer/mono-iOS/trafficControl/src/com/kaproel/trafficControlManager/MainMenuScreen.java:64
at com.kaproel.trafficControlManager.trafficControl.create () [0x00024] in /Users/Piotr/Developer/mono-iOS/trafficControl/src/com/kaproel/trafficControlManager/trafficControl.java:32
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.ios.IOSGraphics.OnLoad (System.EventArgs arg0) [0x00010] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/backends/gdx-backend-iosmonotouch/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/ios/IOSGraphics.java:133
at OpenTK.Platform.iPhoneOS.iPhoneOSGameView.RunWithFrameInterval (Int32 frameInterval) [0x00041] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/OpenGLES/OpenTK_1.0/Platform/iPhoneOS/iPhoneOSGameView.cs:694
at OpenTK.Platform.iPhoneOS.iPhoneOSGameView.Run () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/OpenGLES/OpenTK_1.0/Platform/iPhoneOS/iPhoneOSGameView.cs:652
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.ios.IOSApplication.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication uiApp, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0023e] in /Users/badlogic/jenkins/workspace/libgdx-mac/backends/gdx-backend-iosmonotouch/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/ios/IOSApplication.java:166
at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
at com.kaproel.trafficControlManager.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/Piotr/Developer/mono-iOS/trafficControl-ios/Main.cs:33
```

Please give me same idea of solution

Snipe of code:

```
  public MainMenuScreen(final trafficControl game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.stage = new Stage(0, 0,true);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    this.camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);


    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.local("data/background.png")); // <!-- this line make runtime error
```

Comment: What does your code that loads "data/background.png" look like?

Comment: This looks related (though not too helpful): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660951/getting-java-net-malformedurlexception-in-monodeveloper

Comment: @P.T. i saw before this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660951/getting-java-net-malformedurlexception-in-monodeveloper - but without any good reason

Comment: What you receive if you list the directory with Gdx.files.local("data/").list();

Comment: this command returns correct number of files, but still files are not visible in debugger. I got message unknown protocol: file

Comment: this command returns correct number of files, but still files are not visible for application(i got runtimeerror - not file found).com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: background.png ---> System.Exception: unknown protocol: file
  at java.net.URL..ctor (java.net.URL context, System.String spec, java.net.URLStreamHandler handler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

Answer (score 2):

its might be a problem of png optimization. Have you check this link

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP

Read PNG optimization in this page. Might be that will help you.

Comment: I also checked this site. The advice of optimization PNG didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: just try to load any jpg file in place of this png file. or load anything that is not in png format. Tell me if that file loads or successfully or not???

Comment: changing png to jpg nothing change. still I have error "unknown protocol: file"