# My iOS app suddenly starts force closing immediately

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, libgdx

I have developed an iOS app using libGDX. It is compiled and deployed with the help of Xamarin.iOS, and runs using the Mono framework.

When deploying to my test iPad (a physical iPad, not a simulator), it works great for a while. But after a while (this time, about 12 hours and 5-10 launches), it stops working. When I try to launch it now, it force closes immediately.

When I click the app icon on the iPad, the icon expands and fills the screen (like all apps does when I start them on the iPad), but once the screen has gone black, the app just closes and returns to the iOS menu. No error messages.

The app has been deployed with "Release|iPad".

Any ideas of what could be wrong, or how I can get hold of error messages/logs or something that can help me figure it out?

Comment: Check the console output in Xcode's Organizer.

Comment: see this if this your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037652/cannot-load-a-textureatlas-file-in-ios-using-libgdx-while-loading-through-assetm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode > Organizer > Device Logs.

BTW, this article will you understand the meaning of log:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: Thank you, this helped me learn more about how this stuff worked. However, what really saved me this time is the "Console" right above "Device Logs" in Xcode. When I was able to connect the device to my Mac again, I could provoke the exception, and I got a lot of good information from the console. The crash itself was, of course, extremely simple. Do not call System.out.println() in a libGDX game. Never, not even when it's "just for a couple of seconds". You will forget about it, and it will destroy you at a later time. Use Gdx.app.log() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if you use InvokeInBackground.. if you do.. change over to ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(delegate { {code} } );

I was having huge crashing problems on the current release.. with InvokeInBackground.. once I swapped out to System.Threading.. the problem disappeared.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My problem turned out to be a lot simpler. ;)